# Adding space between Flex rows

Tags: html, angular, css, flexbox

I have this html in an Angular 5 component:

```css
.row>div {
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 20px) !important;
  /* width less horizontal margins */
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div fxLayout="column">

  <div fxLayout="row">
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent">
          <mat-icon>play_button</mat-icon>
          Start Recording
        </button>
  </div>

  <div fxLayout="row">
  </div>

  <div fxLayout="row">
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent">
          <mat-icon>play_button</mat-icon>
          Stop Recording
        </button>
  </div>

  <div fxLayout="row">
  </div>

  <div fxLayout="row">
    <div fxLayout="column">
      <div>
        <mat-checkbox>Firefox</mat-checkbox>
      </div>

      <div>
        <mat-checkbox>Chrome</mat-checkbox>
      </div>

      <div>
        <mat-checkbox>Allow XPath</mat-checkbox>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

it renders to this:

[image]

I tried adding this CSS to increase the spacing between the elements:

```
.row > div {
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 20px) !important; /* width less horizontal margins */
  margin: 10px;
}
```

but that didn't work - how can I add vertical spacing between the elements?

Comment: I got the CSS from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38506233/angular-material-flexbox-how-to-add-margin-between-wrapped-rows

Comment: is it okay to override the existing flex properties with the custom properties?

Comment: I have no idea, to be honest

Comment: i referred their documentation, check the answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have removed the `fxLayout` `row`, and added a custom class to solve the issue.

Please refer their documentation about how they use `row`.
https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxLayout-API

If you are using `<div fxLayout="row">`, it will help you to get horizontal.
[image]

If you use `<div fxLayout="column">`, it will look like the below picture.

[image]

Therefore, better not to complicate your code. So you can use one only 
`column` and get it done

**Here is the snippet.**

```css
.row {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div fxLayout="column">
  <div class="row">
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent">
          <mat-icon>play_button</mat-icon>
          Start Recording
        </button>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent">
          <mat-icon>play_button</mat-icon>
          Stop Recording
        </button>
  </div>
</div>
<div fxLayout="column">
  <div class="row">
    <mat-checkbox>Firefox</mat-checkbox>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <mat-checkbox>Chrome</mat-checkbox>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <mat-checkbox>Allow XPath</mat-checkbox>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this is useful.

Comment: Please put a tick if this solves your issue. Cheers!

Comment: yeah for some reason it's not working, but I think it's the right idea, I am going to keep trying, and if it works, will accept the answer

Comment: You added a custom row class?

Comment: no I didn't add a custom row class, but I will, and it will probably work...I will call it something other than "row" though, just to avoid name clash

Comment: any progress with the it?